# Extracting a pattern that appers multiple times in a string using ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to extract patterns that appert multiple times in a string. For example,getting two an array lay of two digit integers from a string

> wahoaet56oihaioet67jlkiwoeah67ladohwae45lkaowearho56

I thought 
`result="wahoaet56oihaioet67jlkiwoeah67ladohwae45lkaowearho56".match(/([0-9]{2})/)` should give a MatchData object whose `captures` method should give me an array of matched patters, but it seems there is something I am missing. It only give back the first find. Even using `$1,$2,$3` etc doesn't work. I am using ruby

How should I do this?

Comment: what array are you trying to get? `[67, 67]` ?

Comment: I wanted the whole array [56,67,67,45,56]. I can understand why you asked this. thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string.scan(/regex/)
```

should do it

Answer (score 5):

`scan` does what you want:

```
str = "wahoaet56oihaioet67jlkiwoeah67ladohwae45lkaowearho56"
p str.scan(/\d+/) #=> ["56", "67", "67", "45", "56"]
```